# Writing $\cos(\frac{m}{n}\pi)$ in terms of roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots-of-unity

I read somewhere that $\cos(\theta \pi)$ is inside the splitting field of $x^n - 1$. (Assuming that $\theta$ is rational.) I know this field is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ where $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity. This means that we should be able to write $\cos(\theta \pi) = c_0 + c_1\zeta_n + \dots + c_{n - 1}\zeta^{n - 1}$ where $c_i \in \mathbb{Q}$. However, I don't know how I can find these coefficients.

My attempt:
First assume that $\theta = \frac{m}{n}$. We have $\zeta_n = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$. We know $\cos(\pi \theta) + i\sin(\pi \theta) = e^{\frac{m}{n}\pi  i}$.  If I manage to write $\cos(\pi\theta) - i\sin(\pi \theta)$ as a power of $e$, I might be able to add these two and write $2\cos(\pi \theta)$ as an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ using the elements $\{1, \zeta_n, \dots, \zeta_{n}^{n - 1}\}$ but I am stuck here.

Hints would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Note: I found this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268631/using-roots-of-unity-to-find-exact-trig-values). H.Linkhorn has stated in the problem that they can write $\cos(\frac{2}{5}\pi)$ using the $5$-th roots of unity but I didn't understand the process.

Comment: The complex conjugate of $e^{xi}$ (where $x \in \mathbb R$) is $e^{-xi}$. In particular, the complex conjugate of $\zeta_n$ is $\zeta_n^{-1}$, which one can also write, e.g., as $\zeta_n^{n-1}$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Assuming $\theta = \frac{m}{n}$, We can write $2\cos(\pi \theta) = \zeta_n^{\frac{m}{2}} + \zeta_n^{-\frac{m}{2}} = \zeta_{2n}^m + \zeta_{2n}^{-m}$. I should now write $\zeta_{2n}$ using the powers of $\zeta_n$

Comment: Oh that won't work, in general $\cos(\frac{m}{n}\pi)$ is not in the splitting field of $X^n-1$ over $\mathbb Q$. Example: $m=1, n=4$. It is in the splitting field of $X^{2n}-1$. Or equivalently, $\cos(\frac{2m}{n}\pi)$ is in $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)$. See how in the linked post they write out $\cos(\frac{2}{5}\pi)$.